# Why does this php code not send its data to the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I asked a question earlier like this one but I had to change my code a bit and I still do not understand why my database is empty even after I submit an entry.  I am new to php and I am following a book where you can find the source code at: http://www.apress.com/9781430224730.

after I run the code I do not get an error message but my code does not run the way I want it to and I believe it is because no data is being put to the database which is what the rest of the code relies on.

my code where it should be sending data to the database starts on line 66 which I have commented out for you and its next to the else statement.

for whatever reason my code just dosent post anything to the database I really appreciate any help

here is my code:

```
<?php

// Include the functions so we can create a URL
include_once 'functions.inc.php';
include_once 'images.inc.php';

//$e = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'
    && $_POST['submit']=='Save Entry'
    && !empty($_POST['page'])
    && !empty($_POST['title'])
    && !empty($_POST['entry']))
{
    // Create a URL to save in the database
    $url = makeUrl($_POST['title']);
    echo "here";
    if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
    {
        try 
        {
            $img = new ImageHandler("/simple_blog/images/");//not in the textbook
        //print_r($_FILES);
        //exit;
        $img_path = $img->processUploadedImage($_FILES['image']);
        echo '<img src="', $img_path,'" /><br />';//This prints out the image
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
        die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $img_path = NULL;
    }

    // Include database credentials and connect to the database
    include_once 'db.inc.php';
    $db = new PDO(DB_INFO, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

    echo "Image Path: ", $img_path, "<br />";
    //exit; in the book but not on the source
    echo "here";
    // Edit an existing entry
    if(!empty($_POST['id']))
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE entries
            SET title=?, entry=?, url=?
            WHERE id=?
            LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(
            array(
            $_POST['title'],
            $img_path,
            $_POST['entry'],
            $url,
            $_POST['id']
            )
        );
        $stmt->closeCursor();
    }

// Create a new entry
    else               //line 66
    {
        //Save the entry into the database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO entries (page, title, image, entry, url)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($_POST['page'], $_POST['title'], $img_path, 
        $_POST['entry'], $url));
        $stmt->closeCursor();

    // Sanitize the page information for use in the success URL
    $page = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['page']));

    // Send the user to the new entry
    echo "hopefully we get here";
    header('Location: /simple_blog/'.$page.'/'.$url);
    exit;
    }
}
else
{
header('Location: ../');
exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: Any errors? Have you tried a try and catch exceptions to see if there is any?

Comment: You are passing 5 keys in your execute but only 4 bindings in your SQL

Comment: I see you've ignored the suggestion last time that you add some error checking to see if your queries succeed, rather than just assuming that they do.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this, but I think you might need a comma in `$_POST['id'])` in `$stmt->execute()` - Try adding a comma at the end `$_POST['id']),` - *I could very well be wrong*. Thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

You have to bind the results to the query using $stmt->bind_result. After that you have to execute it without any arguments.

Comment: His method of passing an array to the execute method is also allowed.